# Please help me Rotation Animation in android?

Tags: android, animation

i need some example rotate animation to do my project. Anim can be rotate image 360 degree....Can you share me some example?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using  [Rotate3dAnimation in android](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/Rotate3dAnimation.html)

[See this Example](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-rotation-animation.html)